# Can i connect 2 MySql databases to an application developed in simple MVC Framework

Tags: mysql, database

Im developing an application where we are in need to connect to two databases. And the application is developed in PSR Framework. I can easily connect one application. But for the second one, its really tough for me to comprehend and do them. Can someone help me in connecting that?

```
This is a database configuration file.
{
"current_config":"local",
"current_config2":"local2",
"configs":{
     "local":{
        "database":"xxx",
        "username":"root",
        "password":"root",
        "host":"localhost"
    },
    "local2":{
        "database":"mobi",
        "username":"root",
        "password":"root",
        "host":"localhost"
    }
}
}
```

This is how i connected my database with my application.

```
class CyberzoDatabase extends Cyberzo{
protected $dbconn = false;
protected $dbconn2 = false;

public function __construct(){
    //Start Database Connection
    $this->dbconn = $this->dbConnect();
    $this->dbconn2 = $this->dbConnect2();
}

public function connection(){
    return $this->dbconn;
    return $this->dbconn2;
}

public function dbConnect(){
    $connection = false;
    $databaseConfig = $this->getConfig("database");
    $cc = $databaseConfig['current_config'];
    $currentConfig = $databaseConfig['configs'][$cc];
    if(!empty($currentConfig)){
        try {
            $conn = new mysqli($currentConfig['host'],  
$currentConfig['username'], $currentConfig['password'], 
$currentConfig['database']);
            if($conn->connect_errno==0){
                //Connected.
                $connection = $conn;
            }
            else{
                //Connection error.
                echo $conn->connect_error;exit;
            }
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            //throw $e->getMessage();
            echo "Unable to connect database.";exit;
        }
    }

    return $connection;
   }

public function dbConnect2(){
    $connection = false;
    $databaseConfig = $this->getConfig("database");
    $cc = $databaseConfig['current_config2'];
    $currentConfig = $databaseConfig['configs'][$cc];
    if(!empty($currentConfig)){
        try {
            $conn = new mysqli($currentConfig['host'], 
$currentConfig['username'], $currentConfig['password'], 
$currentConfig['database']);
            if($conn->connect_errno==0){
                //Connected.
                $connection = $conn;
            }
            else{
                //Connection error.
                echo $conn->connect_error;exit;
            }
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            //throw $e->getMessage();
            echo "Unable to connect database.";exit;
        }
    }

    return $connection;
}

public function __destruct(){
    //Close Database connection
    if($this->dbconn){
        $this->dbconn->close();//Connection closed.
    }
    //Close Database connection
    if($this->dbconn2){
        $this->dbconn2->close();//Connection closed.
    }
}
}
```

}

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I have edited it. please check now